# Can two separate NAS/File shares be combined into one?

Tags: windows, nas, plex

So, I use a 4 bay Synology NAS to store terabytes worth of media files which a 2008 R2 server running Plex, and multiple other services accesses. I am running out of space on the first NAS, and want to expand horizontally to a second NAS (because I already own it) instead of going through the expense of upgrading all the drives. The second NAS doesn't support NFS LUNs, so simply striping one from each in windows isn't an option.

My question is, is there any way to combine the shares from each NAS as a single share so that all the content is automatically combined? The server uses network drives to download content to the NAS, so it would have to also somehow automatically distribute content between to two shares. Alternatively, I could just use two shares, but all my media applications can only point to one storage location, so it would take a lot of maintenance.

Comment: Since you said you were running 2008 See if this could help you out. Here is the [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479(WS.10).aspx) seems it may help you out let me know if it does not.

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with DFS. It can combine multiple shares under one DNS value, but AFIAK it cannot combine multiple shares under one logical volume.